# populate form with email parameters only

Tags: javascript, html, forms, url, utm

Quick question, I am posting a URL query to a form on a different URL (have to use URL query some restrictions)

My post

```
let url = 'https://go.mysite.com/form.html' + '?' + 'email =' + email_id;
```

I then use that to populate the form email automatically.

```
form.setValues({ Email : decodeURIComponent(document.location.search.substring('email')) });
```

Problem is its filling the email section with  **?emailmail@gmail.com*** rather than just the email **mail@gmail.com**

I need the form to only populate if its a email as we have multiple UTM perimeters on the form page.

dose anyone know how I can edit my code to get this to work?

Comment: I'm not clear on the problem: What is the difference between "mail@gmail.com* not mail@gmail.com"? Do you just need email validation? 

Could you make a Gist to show the problem?

Comment: @samBuchl cheers sorry typo from myside, the form is filled out with ?email-mail@gmail.com. rather than just mail@gmail.com. I can make a Gist. 5 mins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to take a different approach:

```
var address_bar_url = document.location.href
var url = new URL(address_bar_url)

var email = url.searchParams.get('email')

form.setValues({ Email : email });
```

One-liner Soln.:

```
form.setValues({ Email : (new URL(document.location.href)).searchParams.get('email') });
```

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: spot on, used the one liner, nice clean solution.

Comment: Glad it helped!